# Node.js websocket "Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, port, ubuntu-12.04, node.js

Application work fine on localhost .but when its connect to server it getting error.
I connect server through port 22

But my app connecting server port 80.

This is the error

```
 Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
 at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
 at Server._listen2 (net.js:1023:19)
 at listen (net.js:1064:10)
 at net.js:1146:9
 at dns.js:72:18
 at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
 at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
 at startup (node.js:119:16)
 at node.js:906:3
```

i run `netstat -tulpn | grep 22`

Result:

```
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      683/sshd
 tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      683/sshd
```

but i run `netstat -tulpn | grep 80`

Nothing Display.

Any Help.is this server fault?

running `netstat -nlt`

```
     Active Internet connections (only servers)
     Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
     tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
     tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5901          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
     tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5902          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
     tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
     tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6002            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
     tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
     tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
     tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
     tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Running `netstat -anp | grep :80`

```
     tcp        1      0 162.243.145.226:60728   91.189.94.25:80         CLOSE_WAIT  1726/ubuntu-geoip-p
     tcp        1      0 162.243.145.226:47842   74.125.239.148:80       CLOSE_WAIT  8104/epiphany-brows
     tcp        1      0 162.243.145.226:60727   91.189.94.25:80         CLOSE_WAIT  1417/ubuntu-geoip-p
     tcp        1      0 162.243.145.226:58818   198.41.30.199:80        CLOSE_WAIT  8104/epiphany-brows
```

This is source

[source-link](https://github.com/totaljs/examples/tree/master/angularjs-websocket)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the program as root?

If you are not running as root, you cannot bind any program to ports bellow 1024. They are considered privileged ports, and only root can use them.

If you want to run as root, don't. Running as root can create problems if someone exploits your program and gets a shell, and discovers it's a root shell.

Run as an unprivileged user, and change the port from 80 to something above 1024.

Comment: ok.then i use port as 3000.But still getting error.only want i change port in a App?

Comment: I don't know your application, so you will have to discover on the configuration options or files where to change the port.

Comment: yes.in App i change the port.

still getting this error.in server want i do any configuration for port 3000?

Comment: Any help please !!!

Comment: If you can run the application with a debug log setting, you can pinpoint exactly where is the problem. Otherwise nobody can really help you.

Answer (score 0):

From `man 7 ip`

```
ERRORS
       ...

       EADDRNOTAVAIL
              A  nonexistent  interface  was  requested  or  the  requested source
              address was not local.
```

You've probably mistyped the listen IP address to bind to in the config.